# how to check if my text has copyright symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="scDetailLinks">
 <li>
     <h3> ONSTAR®</h3>
 </li>
</ul>
```

how to check if h3 has the copyright symbol using jquery or javascript

Comment: yo, copyright symbol is -  © not r bruver `:)`  and how are you generating this symbol? ASCII (at code level) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about just using `.indexOf()` , like this:

```
if ( $('.scDetailLinks h3').html().indexOf('®') != -1 ) {
   //has copyright 
}
```

If you don't have a source text where to copy ® from , you can also use:

```
if ( $('.scDetailLinks h3').html().indexOf( String.fromCharCode(174) ) != -1 ) {
   //has copyright 
}
```

Comment: @DoGood I've updated my answer with a way to search for it without having to paste the character literally.

Answer (score 1):

You can @Nelson's response or do:

```
if($(".scDetailLinks h3:contains(®)"​)​.length){
  //...
}
```

This checks descendants too:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to check if your text has a copyright symbol:

```
if ($('h3').text().includes('®')) {
  // Do stuff
}
```